# How to enforce synchronous Pub/Sub message processing in a Cloud function making asynchronous API calls?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I've configured a Cloud Function (2nd gen) to be triggered by Pub/Sub (push subscription) whenever new messages are published to the topic. There can be hundreds of messages published at the same time, but I want to process them synchronously and not concurrently.
Despite setting the function's configuration to allow only one maximum instance and one maximum concurrent request per instance, multiple messages are still being processed simultaneously. This behavior appears to stem from asynchronous API calls within my code. As soon as one message initiates an asynchronous API call, another message processing begins, leading to concurrent processing.

How can we process the messages synchronously such that the next message processing should not start until the previous message processing (including asynchronously API calls) is entirely completed?

Here's how the Cloud function's code looks like. Before 2 gets printed, next message processing starts because getBearerToken is an asynchronous function.

```
functions.cloudEvent('processPayload', startProcess);

function startProcess(cloudEvent) {
  console.log(1);
  getBearerToken(function (bearerToken) {
    console.log(2);
    // and so on
  });
}
```

Comment: PubSub is not designed for that. You could use ordering key if you want to respect an order. A better solution would be to use Cloud Task and to set the concurrency parameter, in Cloud Task, not in your functions (even if you can also, it's better to control the concurrency on the client side instead of on the server side)

Comment: I'm trying to understand your requirement - and have a couple of suggestions. Could you make the client side call into a synchronous call, and call the Function directly? This would force the function to finish before continuing with the next bit of logic (May require the use of `await` in JS). Alternatively - you might be able to switch to a `pull` mechanism with PubSub. Just have a single process running somewhere, that pulls a single item from the queue at a time?

Comment: Client side is a webhook (cloud function) and it can receive thousands of requests at the same time (so this can't be synchronous). After that, I am publishing these requests to Pub/Sub and then Pub/Sub triggers another cloud function (concurrency set to 1). But because the cloud function has asynchronous code, the messages are not being processed synchronously.


@guillaumeblaquiere The code in the second cloud function has more than one asynchronous calls dependent on the response status of the previous ones. So, I don't think Cloud Tasks would be a good fit for this requirement.

Comment: Hope this makes sense and if so please lmk if any other architecture in GCP for this requirement.

Comment: I don't know how Cloud Tasks work in depth, but are you saying that instead of publishing the message to Pub/Sub, we can push it to Cloud Task (with max concurrency set to 1) and entire functionality defined in the task, so that it can be sequential?

Comment: Not sure to understand. You mean you get the message, create a background process (fork) and answer OK immediately to PubSub?

Comment: Since this comment has a character limit, I've explained it in this doc. Request you to have a look.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gH7UWJ-6DieIgIaHqA0XtCrjXkU4cyfvU3NaExpL5C8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The Cloud function has combination of synchronous and asynchronous steps. Looking for all of it to be completed as a whole for one message before process for another message is started. Explained the requirement in short in the above doc..

Answer (score 0):

A function whose result depends on the result of another asychronous function effectively becomes asynchronous itself. But when a message arrives, the Pub/Sub framework calls the function synchronously (without `await`) and then again for the next message without waiting for the asynchronous parts to finish. This is demonstrated by the following example.

```js
function asynch(message) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(message);
    }, Math.random(1) * 500 + 500);
  });
}

async function process(message) {
  console.log(await asynch(message));
}

/* Pub/Sub Framework calls function synchronously */
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) process(i);
```

In order to force synchronous execution, you could maintain a queue into which you write these asynchronous functions using the [`Promise::then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method.

```js
function asynch(message) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(message);
    }, Math.random(1) * 500 + 500);
  });
}

var queue = Promise.resolve();
async function process(message) {
  queue = queue
    .then(() => asynch(message))
    .then(console.log);
}

/* Pub/Sub Framework calls function synchronously */
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) process(i);
```

**But** this works only if you have the ability to keep a global variable like the `queue` in the previous example. I doubt that this is the case in such a Pub/Sub framework. Alternatively, you could keep the status of the message queue in a database or some other persistence (which you probably do not have either).

**What this shows:** Using a synchronous message handling mechanism for asynchronous operations with "one message after another" is not possible without substantial extra effort (and probably cost).

Comment: I don't want the second message to even start processing before the first message is fully completed. With your code, it looks like the second message would still enter the cloud function which means processing has started, the only difference is that it waits in a queue. This cloud function has a max timeout of 540 seconds. Hence, waiting in a queue inside the cloud function is not helpful.

Comment: "I don't want the second message to even start processing" - you would have to convince the cloud provider to implement it that way.

Comment: Yeah not sure why asynchronous calls weren't taken into consideration or at least a feature to manage such requirement

Comment: Because they require more effort to be managed, as my answer tried to illustrate.

Comment: Got it. Any other potential ways to do this? I'm open to change the architecture if needed.

Comment: Essentially write all messages into a database and process them one after the other with a separate process. Delete each message after it has been processed.

Comment: I should have given this context before, we have too many messages everyday around 5000. It would result in too many read/writes to DB and might not be cost effective. With pub/sub, it was cost effective. Anyway thanks, I will check more options.